# How to open a properties file from another package on Netbeans (JAVA)

Tags: java, netbeans, nullpointerexception, fileinputstream

I have a bean that needs to take some parameters from a properties file but I can not find it (java.lang.NullPointerException) in order to open it. My bean is in the extra.beans package while the properties file is in the extra.dao package. I am trying to do

```
file = new FileInputStream("database.properties");
prop.load(file);
```

and I have tried any possible combination for the path but I can not find it. I am using Netbeans 7.4. How can I open it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can Use Resource Bundle for that.

```
ResourceBundle resBundle =  ResourceBundle.getBundle("PropertyFileName");  // without extention 
String name=  resBundle.getString("Required Attribute");  // example username
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify the full path. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're loading the properties file into a `Properties` object, try the something like:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("../dao/database.properties"));
```

I don't know your full package structure but using this approach and putting the full path to the properties file would also work, ie: `/extra/dao/database.properties`

Answer (score 0):

```
file = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("extra/dao/database.properties") ;
prop.load(file);
```